# Intersection of 3 cones with sphere, looking for common intersection

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a sphere of defined radius, centered at the origin, and three cones with their base at the origin, defined by a unit vector and cone angle. Each cone intersects the sphere to make a circle. I'm hoping for an efficient procedure to tell whether all three circles share a point in common (I don't need the point). Any ideas? I can solve 2D problems of finding the intersection of three circles, but they rely on computing angles in triangles and I'm uncertain if I can apply that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need a reference to a sphere here.

Let us assume that these cones are defined by

- their axes, directed by **unit** vectors $\vec{D_k}=(x_k,y_k,z_k)$,
- their half aperture angle $\alpha_k$ ($k=1,2,3$) (see "aperture" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone).

The 3 cones will intersect into a common axis directed by a common vector $V=(x,y,z)$ with $\|\vec{V}\|=1$ iff:

$$for \ k=1,2,3 : \ \ \underbrace{\vec{D_k}.\vec{V}}_{\text{dot product}}=\underbrace{\cos \alpha_k}_{c_k} \tag{1}$$

Let us group the 3 constraints in (1) into the following equivalent linear system :

$$\begin{cases}x_1x+y_1y+z_1z&=&c_1\\x_2x+y_2y+z_2z&=&c_2\\x_3x+y_3y+z_3z&=&c_3\\\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

This system has in general (see remark below) a unique solution $(x,y,z)$. Then, with this solution:

> The 3 cones have a common point iff $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$

Here is an equivalent matrix formulation:

Writing system (2) under the form $MX=C$, the test is whether $X=M^{-1}C$ has norm $1$.

Remark : We assume that the 3 axes of the cones aren't coplanar.